# How to practice for piano with chord in one hand and lead in another?

Tags: piano, technique, practice, learning

I am used to playing any song with both of my hand as I am good with harmonium in which with one hand you have to wave a door to flow air. But when it comes to playing actual notes (i.e., lead/melody) of a song with one hand and chords with another hand, I am not able to play that. What exercise or advice would help me with this?

If I need to play chords with both hand or lead notes with both hands, then I am able to play it. But I can't do this concurrently or simultaneously, such that one hand has the lead/melody and the other hand has the chords.

I do play chords naturally, but I don't know staff notation as I learned the North Indian classical notation system `sa` `re` `ga` `ma` `pa` `dha` `ni`.

Comment: I'm going to mark your question as a duplicate, because someone else asked a question about learning both hands on the piano. A link to the duplicate will appear below this comment, and if you click on that link, you should see several answers that should help you with learning to play with both hands. If you still need help after reading those answers, you can either edit your question here or ask a new question. Welcome to Music Practice & Theory!

Comment: @ToddWilcox i read that question in that asker did not mentioned about   chords with one hand and lead notes with another i can play with both hand chords and both hand lead but not alter at same time. so slightly different.

Comment: The other question is not specific to what notes are being played with what hand. Any combinations of notes are considered by the other question. Very often with piano music the two hands are playing very different parts. That's what the other question is about. Your situation is that you want to play different parts with each hand. The answers to the other question tell you how to learn to play two different parts at the same time.

Comment: I think this is a great question, and I do think it's very similar to the one @ToddWilcox linked to. Check out the first answer under the link Todd shared. I believe that answer contains the sort of strategies you are looking for. If it doesn't, then perhaps you could edit the question as Todd suggested, and state "I'm looking for strategies specifically relating to playing chords in the left hand" and explain why the other answer doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @jdjazz its contains strategies of playing simultaneously notes (or at least that what i understand) means some of notes that is need to play by right hands that are lower scale and than some of higher that needs to be play on higher scale. i want to practice to give press with two or one or more fingers with my left hand and play lead notations with my right hand and as song move on change respected finger chords with my left hand. found it very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective method I have found is to begin like so:

Situate yourself at the piano comfortably, and strike the desired first chord with the left hand, and slowly begin to explore the desired lead melody with the right. 
Depress the sustain pedal and let that one chord ring as you practice the lead notes.

Do not attempt to phrase the song's complete rhythm and tempo, but rather, just strike that one chord and let it be enough, in the early stages of your practice.

Then strike the next chord in order, and let it ring as you practice the melody lines. One chord after the next, not attempting to properly play the target song exactly, just laying down a baseline for the muscle memory.

After one or two sessions of this, you will come to realize that your instinct for playing the lead runs with your right hand is comfortable, and you have found the left hand chord phrasings instinctively also. You're just building muscle memory, remember.

When you feel ready, graduate yourself to striking the desired song tempo and chord rhythms with the left hand, and just touch the key notes with your right, not all of them. In this regard, you are building the muscle memory for the desire end state in your left hand.

Within a day or so, you will find that you can play the entire song.
It's a 'crawl, walk, run' progression of practice. 
Good luck!

Comment: great so first only one chord and its related notes without tempo and rhythm than another part. so dividing lead notation as per chords than practice individual and later joined in Synced that made sense. any melody you have in mind? to get started with. your answer sounds like you have a lot experience. and thanks